# Could not connect to development server - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, hadoop-yarn

I am creating an app using react native. I tried to change a file path to an image within my code and when I ran my app on the iOS emulator the following message was displayed.

[image: error]

I have tried a number of different methods such as closing the terminal and running the app again.

I also tried running localhost:8081 in my browser and was given the following message

[image: erorro2]

I have also tried deleting my node_modules folder and running yarn but this still hasn't fixed the problem.

Any ideas as to how I would fix this?

Comment: add `react-native info` in question

Comment: run `export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` in your terminal.

Comment: as the question says I'm trying to run my app on iOS and not Android

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean xcode, remove app in the simulator

```
cd ios
xcodebuild clean
```

run bundler

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the actual IP Address with the "localhost" in the Url and that should fix the issue if the url is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Fully delete the app on the iOS Simulator, then rebuild the app from xcode.